# Translating Dante english to japanese

Tags: translation, particles

Translating Dante's divine Comedy " Follow your own path and let people talk"

I have distilled it to あなたの夢を追う。噂話無視  which I believe translates to " Follow your dreams and ignore the gossips" Is this correct?

How does the translation change if I write  夢を追う。噂話無視

I am inscribing this on a pendant so I need the fewest number of characters with out changing the meaning

Comment: I'm afraid but (あなたの)夢を追う is not imperative and 噂話無視 makes little sense to me.

Comment: That line is a paraphrase of Purgatory (V, 13) as used by Marx in Das Kapital.  The original appears to say something along the lines of "Come after me..." not "Follow your own path...".  One translation is: 我につきて來れ、斯民このたみをその言ふに任まかせよ (山川丙三郎訳)

Comment: Why not translate from the original Italian?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few options here: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=own+path

As to the firm of the main verb, I had a little trouble finding Japanese mottos per se, but corporate and advertising slogans tend to use the volitional, not the imperative. Or just leave the verb off entirely, for that matter (like「未来へ」or 「ステキに」). Which, seeing as you wanted to save space, is what I'll do.

so, arbitrarily: 噂を聞かず、自分の道を

(you could swap the final を for に if you want to emphasise "choosing" your path over "following/walking" it)

I picked the old-fashioned ず ending to sound deliberately archaic/literary.

Comment: I'm sure Tokyo Nagoya will be along shortly to tell me how wrong I am ;)

Comment: Looking at your score, it would be safe to say that other users, too, think that this is a poor answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about [人]{ひと}に[流]{なが}されるな, [他人]{たにん}に流されるな or [周]{まわ}りに流されるな for "Let people talk"?

> [我]{わ}が[道]{みち}を[行]{い}け。(他)人/周りに流されるな。 (我が道=one's own path, 行け=imperative "go")

or

> [自]{みずか}らの[夢]{ゆめ}を[追]{お}え。(他)人/周りに流されるな。 (自ら=oneself, 夢=dream(s), 追え=imperative "pursue")

...maybe??