# Translating “Walk your own path. Let people talk.”

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, usage, archaic-language

After all this time I think I finally have my translation of "Walk your own path. Let people talk." But before I put it in my CAD program, I would like to get an opinion on the word usage and grammar. Here is my translation:

> 汝の仁道は歩く。許すを放語。

I think the words are right but I am not sure about the grammar.

Comment: Original question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13722/translating-dante-english-to-japanese

Comment: Are you deliberately aiming for an archaic style? That would be a hard task even for native speakers, and you seem to have problems with even basic grammar. Sorry, don't mean to discourage you, just wondering what the background of your question is.

Comment: I'm Japanese, but I've never heard of the word 放語 and 仁道. (They're read ほうご and じんどう, right?) One of my Japanese dictionaries (小学館現代国語例解辞典) lists 法語, 邦語 and 人道 but not 放語 and 仁道.

Comment: I found it in 大辞林, however it also indicated it's a synonym for 放言.

Comment: @snailboat thanks for linking this. The other thread was closed so I figured I should ask this here.

Comment: @Chocolate I admit the first was pieced together. I wanted a verb and only got nouns so I exercised poetic license. I found the Kanji for careless  and paired it with 語. 

 The second, being "divine path", I took to meaning ones one path to enlightenment. It had the right feel... again.. Poetic license. 

(Yes the Kana are correct)

Of course having Native input is extremely helpful.

Comment: @Chocolate Is there a better way to translate "Let people talk" to get across "Ignore the naysayers and rumor-mongers."?

Comment: @Chris To me, Yang Muye's ひとのいうにまかせよ。([人]{ひと}の[言]{い}うに[任]{まか}せよ。) and ひとのげんをおそれず、・・・ (人の[言]{げん}を[恐]{おそ}れず...) sound very good as "Let people talk /Ignore the...". (These sound archaic and literary, so probably poetic, too. 人の言うに任せよ would be like 人の言うことなど、放っておけ。 in modern Japanese, but this wouldn't sound poetic.) And... I tried but couldn't think of anything more than what I have posted on your previous question, sorry.

Comment: @Chris And for the latter part, again I think Yang Muye's [己]{おのれ}の[道]{みち}を[行]{い/ゆ}け or [進]{すす}め would be the best translation. ([己]{おのれ}, which is like "(my/your)self" or "(your/my) own", sounds more literary than 自分.)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5m1z8B7fFs

Answer (score 7):

I will have a try.

```
人ノ言ヲ懼レズ、己ノ道ヲ進メ
ひとのげんをおそれず、おのれのみちをすすめ
```

or

```
己ノ道ヲ行キ、人ノ言フニ任セヨ
おのれのみちをゆき、ひとのいうにまかせよ
```

There is a saying I love very much, but much harder to understand than my translations, if you are not familiar with 漢文.

```
千万人ト雖モ吾往カン
せんまんにんといえどもわれゆかん

Original text:  自反而縮。雖千萬人吾往矣。 -- 孟子　公孫丑上
Explanation given by 大辞林: 
自ら省みて正しければ，敵対者や反対者がどんなに多くとも，恐れることなく自分の信ずる道を進もう。
```

Comment: +1 for katakana particles and okurigana.

Comment: I think they both are good translations, sound natural, too. Maybe OP wanted a kanji+hiragana version??

Comment: 言フニ does not equal いうに.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-native, I'm not certain if there is a perfectly native way to express this.  Hence, my answer will focus on refining what's presented.

Getting started, by using 汝【なんじ】 in the first half you're definitely trying to give it an archaic feel; if you're not deliberately doing that, 自分 would be a better choice.

Using 歩く in the first sentence literally means "to walk", but comes off as a bit stilted to me; 進む【すすむ】 ("to advance") is what I've more often come across in such situations.  Also, the original English is in the imperative, so the translation should reflect this.

As such, my rendering for the first part would be:

> 自分の仁道を進め。

The second part is a little more difficult.  The original English is "Let people talk," however the words you've chosen—when arranged for proper grammar—ask that the hearer forgive indiscreet remarks.  By not specifying whose remarks to forgive, it creates further ambiguity.

As such, the translation depends on the nature of the talking you're referring to.  If you really did mean it as an admonition to forgive others' indiscretions, then I would revise it to something along the lines of the following:

> 人の放語を許せ。

If you're really meaning simply "allow people to speak", then I would probably go with something more along the lines of the following, which is literally more along the lines of "listen to what people have to say":

> 人の言葉を聞け。

Comment: Also non-native for the Japanes, but I think 歩む（あゆむ） is better than 進む in this case, because 進む presumes a type of advance that I definitely don't hear in "walk your own path" (native for the English)

Comment: Definitely not going for the archaic, just dealing with limited space. So thank you. Noticed you replaced は with を
Is that always the case for the imperative?　

Thank you for the correction.

Actually, I was going for the admonition (Hey I screwed up and got one right!!!....well almost) Thank you here as well.